# Linked List Malloc() on insertion?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

So I've been trying to make sure I SOLIDLY understand linked lists. Here is what I have so far:

```
typedef struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;

}node;

int main()
{
    node *HEAD = create(5);
    printf("Address:%p Value:%i\n", HEAD, HEAD->num);
    HEAD = insert(HEAD,3);
    printf("Address:%p Value:%i\n", HEAD, HEAD->num);
    HEAD = insert(HEAD,7);
    printf("Address:%p Value:%i\n", HEAD, HEAD->num); 
    return 0;
}

node* create(int value)
{
    node *HEAD = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(HEAD == NULL)
    {
        printf("Space Unable to be allocated for HEAD\n");
    }
    HEAD->num = value;
    HEAD->next = NULL;
    return HEAD; 
}

node* insert(struct node *HEAD,int value)
{
    node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    new_node->num = value;
    new_node->next = HEAD;
    HEAD = new_node;
    return HEAD;
}

void print(struct node *HEAD)
{
    node *trav = HEAD;
    while(trav != NULL)
    {
        printf("Value in Linked List:%i\n",trav->num);
        trav = trav->next;
    }
}
```

So this works and prints out 5,3,7 like it should. However when drawing it out on paper, the `node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));` sort of confuses me a bit. Since it seems to me that we are creating a new pointer called "new_node" each time on insertion....which seems like a lot of leftover pointers are just left dangling. What would make more sense is for the `new_node` to change each time to point to the malloc'd space for the new node thats being inserted.

So am I doing something wrong here, or when I malloc something with the same name is the old one just getting re-assigned (if that make sense?) or should I be free()'ing the new_node after it's been inserted each time?

Thanks

Comment: You are not inserting the new values, you are just creating new nodes and print them. Look at where you "link" the head node and the newly created node. You won't find it.

Comment: Local variables inside a function cease to exist once the function they are in returns. *And* "the new_node to change each time to point to the malloc'd space for the new node thats being inserted" is already what's happening! Try using a debugger to step through the code line by line and check the variables and their values. Or simply print out everything (remember that `printf` uses `"%p"` to print a `void *` (and yes you need to cast the pointers)).

Comment: I would suggest you to first use some working example for your understanding the write your own code.

Comment: It does indeed seem to work however, I added in a print function which traverses the linked list and prints the value and it does indeed print (7,3,5) like it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not be freeing the *new_node*. If you do that, then after the program is out ou function *insert* your variable *HEAD* will be pointing to a **NULL** location.

What's really happening is everytime you use malloc there is some memory space allocated to it. So in case of function *insert* your variable *new_node* points to it and then you make that node *HEAD*.

Now when the program exits that function, *new_node*  as a variable gets deleted but the memory space it pointed to, is now being pointed at by *HEAD* and all the nodes you have created till this point can be reached by traversing *HEAD*. Therefore you are left with no dangling pointers.

Comment: So is my solution right? because basically everyone is saying im not doing it right ha. But you seem to be right, I printed off &new_node after each insert and it stays the same.

Valgrind does show that I have memory locked up, so I should be freeing at the END of the program i'd assume right?

Comment: @msmith1114 I don't think there is something wrong with your code. You can write a linked list code any way you want. Like, here you are inserting a node and making it the _HEAD_, what many people do is, insert the node at the end.

See this page for further understanding.
http://quiz.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/

Answer (score 3):

Think linked list like train cars, every time you add a new car, you need to connect it to the last car, or the train won't pull the newly added node.

So the pseudo code should be like this:

```
main {
    // create the locomotive
    head = create_new_node(5);
    // link new car
    insert(head, 7);
    // link new car
    insert(head, 9);
    // hit the road jack
    dump(head);
}
```

Creating a new car

```
create_new_node(value) {      
    // get the resources for a new car  
    node *p = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    // load the car
    p->value = value;
    // attach the car connector
    p->next = null;
    // get the new car on field
    return *p;
}
```

Inserting to the end of the train

```
insert(head, val) {
    node *p = head;
    // go to the last train car
    while(p->next != null) p = p->next;
    // create new train car
    node *n = create_new_node(val);
    // link it to the last car
    p->next = n;
}
```

Inspecting the train

```
dump(head) {
   // i don't want the 'head' to be changed, so I use a reference instead.
   node *p = head;
   // loop each car + the locomotive until end is reached
   while(*p != null)
   {
      // count the load
      write p->value;
      // inspect the next car
      p = p->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: Im just adding it on at the front, which seems just as good? im not sure I see the issue with mine? It avoids the need for traversing the entire list to the end when I can just insert it at the beginning/

Comment: @msmith1114 Not necessarily, you can also have a pointer to the end of the list, and insert nodes there, without having to traverse the whole list. Linked lists have `O(1)` insertion, which means you can insert nodes at the front or end of the list. You should have a look at LIFO and FIFO structures.

Comment: @msmith1114 You are not adding it to the front by the way, you are losing the references when you set `head` to the new value. The important thing here, you need to be able to read all the values with the given head pointer.

Comment: @TahaPaksu I am able to read them though, see the print function i edited in (Which does work and prints out the correct values. I DO think that im losing the new_node references because im making a new one each time. Which is what I was asking about.

Comment: @msmith1114 remove all the prints in between, and try to get all values on the end. You'll understand what I mean.

Comment: Right, I understand what you are saying, ignore that part. The print function itself does traverse through the linked list and prints out the values correctly. Unless you are talking about the print function as well.

Im assuming you are talking about these:
`printf("Address:%p Value:%i\n", HEAD, HEAD->num);`

Comment: Yes I'm talking about them. And yes, now it should work with the newly added print function. But you altered the question itself, people won't see the point that I've written this answer :)

Comment: The point of this question was my confusion with `node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));` and if I was basically leaving pointers out there just dangling. But  @deepakgupta8777 explained that the new_node pointer is going to drop off  at the end of the function. I wasnt actually asking about the printf's in main so I apologize if I misrepresented the question that way.

Comment: This answer also covered where to use the new allocated memory pointers. I just wanted you to fully understand the logic here.